# SQL - Sum of positive and negative numbers using subquery

Tags: sql

I have a table which contains positive and negative numbers. I have to find out sum of positive and negative numbers using sub query

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you encounter? This site can help you with solving a problem, but it is no a place to get a free solution. (By free I mean without effort and understanding)

Answer (score 21):

Your question isn't very clear (no table nor column names given), nor is it clear why you need a subquery (never a good idea if it can be avoided). You can get the values that you want by use of the 'case' statement

The following *counts* the number of positive and negative values

```
select sum (case when acolumn >= 0 then 1 else 0 end) as positive,
       sum (case when acolumn < 0 then 1 else 0 end) as negative
from table
```

whereas the following *sums* the number of positive and negative values

```
select sum (case when acolumn >= 0 then acolumn else 0 end) as positive,
       sum (case when acolumn < 0 then  acolumn else 0 end) as negative
from table
```

Comment: or more likely `THEN acolumn ELSE 0` for OPs needs - since he says he wants a `SUM`, not a `COUNT`

Answer (score 6):

For the sum of the negative :

```
SELECT SUM(numberColumn) FROM tableFoo WHERE numberColumn < 0
```

For the sum of the positive:

```
SELECT SUM(numberColumn) FROM tableFoo WHERE numberColumn >= 0
```

To combine the two (with QUERY1 and QUERY2 being the two previous queries):

```
SELECT (QUERY1), (QUERY2)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select sum(case when a>=0 then a else 0 end) as positive,
sum(case when a<0 then a else 0 end) as negative
from a
```

Answer (score 0):

By using CTE(Common table Expression) we can get the output.

```
;WITH Psum_CTE
AS
(   SELECT SUM(num) AS PositiveSum
    FROM sample
    WHERE num>=0 
)
,Nsum_CTE
AS
(
    SELECT SUM(num) AS NegativeSum
    FROM sample
    WHERE num<0
)

SELECT PositiveSum,NegativeSum
FROM Psum_CTE,Nsum_CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (
    (SELECT SUM(numberColumn) FROM tableFoo WHERE numberColumn < 0 ) -
    (SELECT SUM(numberColumn) FROM tableFoo WHERE numberColumn > 0)
) AS totalCalculation
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sign`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sign-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to separate the values:

```
select Sum( ( Sign( n ) + 1 ) / 2 * n ) as PositiveSum,
  Sum( -( Sign( n ) - 1 ) / 2 * n ) as NegativeSum
  from YourTableOData;
```

`Sign` returns `1`, `0` or `-1` depending on the sign of the input value. A little arithmetic can convert that into `1` or `0` depending on the sign: `( Sign( n ) + 1 ) / 2` is `1` for all positive values, otherwise `0`. Note that the check for negative values (`( Sign( n ) - 1 ) / 2`) returns `-1` or `0`, hence the negation (`-`) to avoid flipping the sign of the value that is being summed.